# if in clause have many parameters mysql db could bear this

Tags: mysql

I'd like to page query products, and pass some artisan id list as a query condition, e.g.

```
select * from product where artisan_id in ("0051e37697b14304a92990978189d337",...) and ... limit 0, 10;
```

before execute above query I have to filter those matched artisan id, e.g. belong to a particular location, have the particular gender, nick and so on.

Some query conditions is not must have to enter, so in final may be artisan id list is much big, e.g. thousands. so I wonder mysql db if could bear this pressure?

Because joint query sql is very complex and difficult to expand, especially some table have huge rows, in this case joint query is very slow, so I have to query single table many times to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you asking if a database can handle many where conditions or if a `in` clause can handle many parameters? It is not very clear right now.

Answer (score 1):

In MySql case the [`IN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) is limited by a configuration called [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) which by default is 1048576 bytes

In others RDBMs I've worked with An `IN` clause is limited to 1000 items such as Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQLServer

So to solve your problem you would have to programmatically create the `IN` filter as

```
`AND (    someField in ( 'id1', 'id2', ..... 'id1000' ) 
       or someField in ( 'id1001', 'id1002', ..... 'id2000' ) 
       or .... )`
```

I suggested 1000 items because of other RDBMs but for MySql and your specific case it may be less since your IDs is large strings as `'0051e37697b14304a92990978189d337'`

And a side note: **Always use single quotes for strings in database queries**